# Passando uma variável para annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou fazendo a leitura de um JSON(usando Jackson) e queria pegar esse valor e atribuir para a Annotation do Spring-Boot. Seria possível ? Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 14400000)
    public void timelineUser() {
        log.info("Iniciando serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
        TimeLineUserApi timeLineUserApi = new TimeLineUserApi();
        timeLineUserApi.run();
        log.info("Serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
    }
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = umavariavelqualquer) 
public void timelineUser() {
    log.info("Iniciando serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
    TimeLineUserApi timeLineUserApi = new TimeLineUserApi();
    timeLineUserApi.run();
    log.info("Serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
}
```

Agradeço desde já pela compreensão.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o que você pode fazer é usar uma variavel que foi declarada em algum arquivo de configuração(.yml, .propertiers) do spring, sendo assim ficaria algo desse tipo:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${uma.propriedade.delay.seconds}")
public void timelineUser() {
    log.info("Iniciando serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
    TimeLineUserApi timeLineUserApi = new TimeLineUserApi();
    timeLineUserApi.run();
    log.info("Serviço da API de Tweets por usuário finalizado");
}
```

Se não ficou muito claro, pode ir me perguntando nos comentários da resposta.